# MySQL JSON - How to use JSON_SET on all elements of a matched path?

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to figure out a `JSON_SET()` query that would add `{key2: 2}` to all elements of `$.a`:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "key1": 1
    },
    {
      "key1": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Obviously, this fails because of `'*'` in the path:

```
UPDATE table SET json=JSON_SET(json, '$a[*].key2', 2);
```

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this will have to be done in a stored procedure that uses `JSON_LENGTH()` to get the number of elements in the array, then updates each of them.

Comment: I really hate the people who decided it would be a good idea to add JSON to SQL. It makes it seem like it's OK to denormalize your schema, but except for the simplest uses it's still a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) and [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg):

```sql
UPDATE `table`
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_SET(`der`.`_json`, '$.key2', 2)
      ) `json_key2`
    FROM
      `table`,
      JSON_TABLE(`table`.`json`,
      '$.a[*]'
      COLUMNS(
        `_json` JSON PATH '$'
      )
    ) `der`
    GROUP BY
      `der`.`_json`  
  ) `der`
SET `table`.`json` = JSON_SET(
  `table`.`json`,
  '$.a',
  `der`.`json_key2`
);
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sWwTuvDAqveB1TVbbTFouX/1).